# How to aggregate its previous 30 days for each line in MySQL without using self-join?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregation, window-functions, analytic-functions

Suppose we have a table Named `UserSessions`. Each user can have multiple sessions in a day or across different days. The columns of this table are

```
UserSessions table: 
---------------------
SessionID (int) PK, 
UserID (int), 
datetime (datetime)
```

and sample data look like this:

```
1, 1001, 2017-01-01  
2, 1001, 2017-01-01  
3, 1002, 2017-01-01   
4, 1002, 2017-01-02  
...
```

Now, we want to write a query that display the count of distinct users in last 30 days for each day. What is the best way to do this?

An obvious solution is to use self-join, but we hope we can avoid that.
Does it has something to do with the window function? I am wondering if there is a feature that, for each line, we can aggregate within x rows ahead and y rows after.

For example, similar questions like "what is the average of orange price in a window of 30 days ahead of each day recorded so far" etc. To be more specific, it's like asking an aggregation over a period of x-30 to x-1 days on day x.

Comment: 'I want to avoid that'

Answer (score 0):

you could use a group by  ..eg:

```
  select UserId, count(*)
  from my_table 
  where datetime between date_sub(now(), interval 30 day ) 
                        AND date_sub(now(), interval 1 day )
  group by UserID
```